# Does "sticker" have a transliteration?

Tags: transliteration

I hear people use the English loan word `sticker` a lot in Chinese, perhaps even more than `粘粘`, `贴贴` or what have you.

Although a loan word, `sticker` prounced in Chinese **mainly** sounds like a transliteration with a combination of:

> si • ti • ke

or

> si • di • ke

I would imagine it would be written something like:

- 斯提克
- 斯蒂克

but, I have not come across any such transliteration in written form, yet.

Is there a transliteration of `sticker` in Chinese?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a transliteration. 贴纸 is good enough for translation.
If you hear anybody say 不干胶, they may also mean stickers.
I guess that you hear some Chinese saying "sticker" in English, is because they can't remember the Chinese word 贴纸, so they use English instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there's no transliteration in Chinese for "sticker". In Chinese, especially in Shanghainese, there are many transliterations for English words. For example, "司迪克" for “stick（walking stick）”，“斯博灵” for “spring lock”，“水门汀” for “cement”，“拉三” for “lass”，etc.

As for "sticker", if you have ever heard any Chinese says,it is just an occasionally borrowed word from English. That means if you write "give me a sticker" in Chinese, it would be "给我一张sticker". There's no Formal Chinese transliteration of it.

In Chinese, we use such words like "贴纸"，"粘纸", or "不干胶标签" for "sticker".

Answer (score 0):

To say sticker, you would use, "貼紙" (Tiēzhǐ).

You won't be able to find a phonetic translation, for the word "Sticker." Depending on which dialect, some people use english within their Chinese. We joke around and call this "Chinglish."

So if you're transcribing or looking at subtitles, you would see the English word written out in English instead of phonetically:

> 他買了"stickers"

Usually the only time that you would write something out in phonetic Chinese is if there isn't a Chinese word for it already (i.e. English names)

Obama = 奧巴馬 (àobāmǎ)